# How to implement "select all" feature on infinite scoll / server-side pagination?

Tags: javascript, pagination, infinite-scroll

Paged / filtered list is common and easy to implement, either plain javascript or with some frameworks.

But when it comes to batch operations that goes beyond current view, like item count, last page and selections, things get really ugly.

Is there any common practise out there?

Comment: Nice answers were given here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/113911/infinite-scroll-and-select-all

Comment: wow thanks, I do came up with quite a few number of ways in this 6 years of time.